# Change color when clicked using input color

Tags: javascript

I want change color title on click it.
I write next:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var color = document.getElementById('input-color');
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
    function chancheColor(){
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                color.click();

                color.addEventListener('change', function () {
                    var name = this.value;

                    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                        elems[i].style.color = name;
                    }
                });

            });
        }
    }
    chancheColor();
};
```

```html
<input id="input-color" type="color">
<p class="title">First</p>
<p class="title">First</p>
<p class="title">First</p>
```

I simulate a click on  
color.click();
Is it true?

Now my function сhange the color for all titles
beacause I have a second cycle for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
I don't know, how get the current value of the title which was clicked.

And generally how is it possible to transfer a parameter in function if it is caused like this?
color.addEventListener('change', function () {});

Comment: At each `click` at `elems[i]` you are attaching an additional `change` event handler to `color`

Answer (score 0):

you are attaching event handler to color multiple times in for loop, no need for that. and the loop inside event handler is not required, you just have to change the color of clicked 'p' for that you can save the clicked p and changed its color inside change event handler of input-color, something like this:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var color = document.getElementById('input-color');
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
    var currentElem;
    function chancheColor(){
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                currentElem = this;
                color.click(); 
            });
        }
    }

    color.addEventListener('change', function () {
                var name = this.value;
                currentElem.style.color = name;
            });
    chancheColor();
};
```

```html
<input id="input-color" type="color">
<p class="title">First</p>
<p class="title">First</p>
<p class="title">First</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

At each `click` at `elems[i]` you are attaching an additional `change` event handler to `color`.

Move `change` event attachment outside of `for` loop.

> And generally how is it possible to transfer a parameter in function
>   if it is caused like this?

You can use `Element.dataset` to set the clicked element `.dataset` property to `true` and set siblings `.dataset` to `false`, use `.querySelector()` with attribute selector `".title[data-clicked=true]"` to select only the element which was clicked within `change` handler.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var color = document.getElementById('input-color');
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

  function chancheColor() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++) {
          elems[j].dataset.clicked = false;
        }
        this.dataset.clicked = true;
        color.click();
      });
    }
  }
  color.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var clicked = document.querySelector(".title[data-clicked=true]");
    if (clicked) {
      console.clear();
      clicked.style.color = this.value;
    }
    else {
      console.log("Click a .title element to change the elements' color");
    }
  });
  
  chancheColor();
};
```

```html
<input id="input-color" type="color">
<p class="title">First</p>
<p class="title">First</p>
<p class="title">First</p>
```